# From 2.93, AO baking result becomes unusable

Tags: baking

From 2.93.X, to latest 3.0.0, AO baking result looks like this:

[image]

Even with default settings (only sample settings are changed from default).

For comparison, here is a normal AO map baked with 2.79:

[image]

How could this happen and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

OK I may found the way to solve this...

I removed the materials attached to the model, added a default one, added an image node, created an image, then I started baking. After a while Blender outputs an normal AO map as what it should be.

I don't have to do this in 2.79 and 2.8x.

Don't know what they have changed in 2.9x and 3.0 caused the problem.